# IDE0029 Null check can be simplified C# 6.0 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my visual studio 2017, there is a message in Error List windows like this.

**IDE0029 Null check can be simplified**

I google it and found this link [Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) but i don't understand.

My code is simple like this:

```
string varIP = Request.UserHostAddress != null ? Request.UserHostAddress : "IP null";
```

How to simplify it again?

Comment: What you want do do? Simplify the code

Comment: @AkshayBheda yes

Comment: If you put your cursor on that line (it should have a squiggle underneath it), then click the lightbulb icon in the margin (or press `Ctrl+.`), then VS will give you an option to simplify it, and it will make the change that the answers below suggest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string varIP = Request.UserHostAddress != null ? Request.UserHostAddress : "IP null";
```

Can be re-written with the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
string varIP = Request.UserHostAddress ?? "IP null";
```

This will use the value of `UserHostAddress`, unless it is null in which case the value to the right ("IP null") is used instead.

If there is any possibility of `Request` being null, you can additionally used the null-conditional operator that you mentioned in the question:

```
string varIP = Request?.UserHostAddress ?? "IP null";
```

In this case if the `Request` is null then the left hand side will evaluate as null, without having to check `UserHostAddress` (which would otherwise throw a `NullReferenceException`), and the value to the right of the null-coalescing operator will again be used.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **null-conditional operator** along with [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`) to simplify your code:

```
string varIP = Request?.UserHostAddress ?? "IP null";
```

it means
if `Request?.UserHostAddress` is not null then it will assign the `Request.UserHostAddress` value to `varIP`,
else `"IP null"` is assign to `varIP`

Comment: Just pointing out that this isn't *entirely* equivalent - the OP's code doesn't check whether `Request` is null, but this answer does. A closer equivalent is `Request.UserHostAddress ?? "IP null";`, without the null-conditional operator. I'm not saying that the null-conditional is a bad thing to have here, just that it isn't *strictly* necessary to get equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will automatically change this for you.

First, go to the offending line (you can double-click the message in the Errors List to do this). You'll see that there are 3 dots underneath `Request` - this means that a refactoring is available:

[image: Refactoring available]

There's also a yellow lightbulb in the margin. Click the lightbulb:

[image: Suggested Refactoring]

You can see the change that Visual Studio suggests. Click "Use coalesce expression" to make the change:

[image: Refactored]

You can also use the shortcut `ctrl+.` to do the same thing with less clicking. With your cursor somewhere (anywhere) on that click, press `ctrl+.`, and the same menu appears as if you had clicked the lightbulb. Press `Enter` to accept the change.

This means you can quickly fix your code:

1. Double-click the message in the Errors List
2. `Ctrl+.` then `Enter`

Refactorings are available in lots of places, as indicated by the lightbulb. Sometimes you have to have your cursor in a particular place, which makes it hard to discover what's on offer. For example there are refactorings available to automatically implement constructors or generate fields/properties, automatically assign parameters to properties and add null checks, turn foreach loop into for loop and linq, and vice versa, and many many more.

Answer (score 0):

```
string varIP = Request.UserHostAddress ?? "IP null";
```

if `Request.UserHostAddress` not null the value gets assigned orelse the part after `??` gets assign `varIP`.